# Getting value of unknown number of inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a site generated mainly in PHP. On one page PHP generates a number of dropdowns, the number of which is depending on items in my DB.

The number of dropdowns can change but I want to be able to count them and get the values for each of them in JS/jQuery.

At the moment the dropdowns all have the same class name but I think I'm going to have to try give them all individual IDs.

I know I could the amount of items like this:

```
var ammount = $(".myclass").length;
```

I just need some way of looping through these to get the individual values like this, without just picking up the first value of that class each time:

```
var input =$(".myclass").value;
```

I think I'm going to have to go with individual IDs being generated by the PHP but was just wondering if there was another way to do it.

Comment: `$(".myclass").each(function(){ console.log($(this).value); });`

Comment: "I think I'm going to have to try give them all individual ID's."...if you want to count them and perform the same action on each one, then quite the opposite. Having a class in common is ideal so you can easily select them as a group. Use a .each loop to loop through all the dropdowns and then you can get the value from each one individually. https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".myclass").each(function(i,e) { 
    console.log(e); //e gives you current item in loop
});
```

or

```
$(".myclass").each(function() { 
  console.log($(this).value); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the values in an `array`, by iterating over all these elements and pushing their values to the `array`:

```
var vals = [];
$(".myclass").each(function() {
  vals.push($(this).val());
});
```

If you want to get the sum of all these inputs :

```
var sum = vals.reduce((a,b) => (+a + +b));
```

**Demo:**

```js
var vals = [];

$(".myclass").each(function() {
  vals.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(vals);


//Calculating sum of values
var sum = vals.reduce((a,b) => (+a + +b));
console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="myclass" value="10" />
<br/>
<input type="text" class="myclass" value="20" />
<br/>
<input type="text" class="myclass" value="30" />
<br/>
<input type="text" class="myclass" value="40" />
<br/>
<input type="text" class="myclass" value="50" />
<br/>
```